# How to setup activerecord + models in a file, then re-use it in all other script files?

Tags: ruby

I have a bunch of different .rb command line script files that perform various tasks, but they all use the same database.

I'm coding the 2nd .rb file, and the 1st one has all references to ActiveRecord, db connections, and classes that represent my models etc.

Is it possible to move all this to another file, and then just import the file in each of my .rb files?

How would this work?

Answer (score 2):

`require` basically goes out and runs another file in the context of the current ruby process if it hasn't be required yet. if your db file is called `models.rb` and it is living in a sub directory called `lib`, it would look like this

```
require 'lib/models'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to read [`Modules`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_modules.html), which is part of the "Pickaxe Book", AKA [`Programming Ruby`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/).